# Automatically convert XML to JSON in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

In WSO2 ESB, changing some properties is possible to change the messageType from XML to JSON, what about the easiest way, even not caring about the format, tags, whatsoever, here an example:

```
string SfID = xmls:getString(soapResponse, "/*:queryResponse/*:result/*:records/*:Id/text()" );
string Sfusername = xmls:getString(soapResponse, "/*:queryResponse/*:result/*:records/*:Name/text()" );

json jsPayload = `{"SFUser":
                   {"Sfusername":"Sfusername" ,
                   "SfID":"SfID"}
                  }`;

jsons:set(jsPayload,"$.SFUser.SfID" , SfID);
jsons:set(jsPayload,"$.SFUser.Sfusername" , Sfusername);

message response = {};

messages:setJsonPayload(response,jsPayload);
```

I'd like for whatever response in SOAPXMLResponse, to convert to a JSON using the same tags.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer from a colleague:

Here is the example (Salesforce execution):

```
@http:GET{}
    @http:Path {value:"/execute"}
    resource querySalesForceWithParams(message m ) {
        xml queryOptions = `<urn:QueryOptions xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><urn:batchSize>200</urn:batchSize></urn:QueryOptions>`;
        headers = [queryOptions];
        soapResponse = salesforcesoap:ClientConnector.query(sales, headers, "Select c.Reason, c.IsClosed, c.Id, c.Description, c.CreatedDate From Case c");
        system:println(xmls:toString(soapResponse));

        message response = {};

        json jsonPayload = (json) soapResponse;

        messages:setJsonPayload(response,jsonPayload);    

        reply response;

    }
```